# Let $A$ be a real $4\times 4$ matrix with characteristic polynomial $(x^2+1)^2$. Which of the following is true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{4\times 4}$ have characteristic polynomial $(x^2+1)^2$. Which of the following is true?

1. $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$ but not over $\mathbb R$
2. $A$ is nilpotent
3. $A$ is invertible
4. There is no such matrix $A$.

Comment: The existence of $A$ is guaranteed by the existence of companion matrix. To verify invertibility, you only need to check if $0$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial or not. There is no need to expand $(x^2+1)^2$, calculate *all* eigenvalues of $A$ or calculate the determinant. Every nilpotent matrix is singular (because some of its power evaluates to zero). So, if $A$ is invertible, it can't possibly be nilpotent. As for diagonalisability, no, $A$ is not necessarily diagonalisable over $\mathbb C$. I'll leave the construction of counterexample to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If $A$ has same minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial then
  $A$ can not be diagonalizable.

Since we know that $A$ is diagonalizable iff minimal polynomial is product
of distinct linear factor.

---

- $A$ can not be nilpotent since eigen value of a nilpotent matrix are $0$
  only

---

- $A$ is invertible for sure.

---

**Proof of invertibility:**

Given, characteristic equation is $(x^2+1)^2=0$.

$\implies (x^2+1)^2=0$

$\implies (x^2+1)=0$

$\implies x= i, i, -i, -i$

Therefore determinant of $A$ is:

$\implies \det(A)=(i)^2\times (-i)^2=-1\times-1=1\neq0$

And we know that $A$ is invertible iff $\det A\neq0$

Therefore matrix $A$ is  invertible.

---

- Such a matrix always exists

For Example

$$ A=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&-1\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&-2\\0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Then Characteristics polynomial of $A$ is $(x^2+1)^2$.

Comment: A matrix can be diagonalizable if its characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomial are the same. Take, for instance, the $ 3 \times 3 $ diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $ 1, 2, 3 $.

Comment: No I don't agree you. I think you don't know the following result :

A matrix B is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial is product of distinct linear factor.

Comment: I have no clue how that refutes what I said.

Answer (score 4):

$A$ is invertible for sure.

---

Given, characteristic equation is $(x^2+1)^2=0$.

$\implies (x^2+1)^2=0$

$\implies (x^2+1)=0$

$\implies x= i, i, -i, -i$

Therefore determinant of $A$ is:

$\implies \det(A)=(i)^2\times (-i)^2=-1\times-1=1$

Since, matrix $A$ is non-singular, so, inverse of matrix $(i.e., A^{-1})$ is always exists.

Comment: The product of the roots (that is, determinant) can be directly found out from the characteristic polynomial though!

Answer (score 3):

$$P_A(x)=(x^2+1)^2=x^4+2x^2+\color{red}1$$
$$\operatorname{det}(A)=1$$
$A$ is invertible.

Comment: It would be helpful to show why the others are false. Like, since $\det(A)=1\not=0\implies \det(A^n) = \det(A)^n = 1 \not = 0$ and hence $A$ can't be nilpotent.

Comment: Thanks, If $A_{n\times n}$ be an convertible matrix then $A_{n\times n}$ is not nilpotenet.let $A^{m}=0$ then $A=0$

Comment: Why down vote? :)

Comment: I didn't of course. I upvoted. I never downvote

Comment: I know Aritra..

Answer (score 2):

$(x^2+1)^2 = 0 \implies x^4+2x^2+1 = 0$

By [Cayley–Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), $A^4 + 2 A^2 +I = 0$ , where $I$ is unit matrix and $0$ is zero matrix.

then $A \times (A^3 +2A) = -I \implies A \times (-A^3 -2A) = I$

So $A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anyone having addressed the nilpotency. Can be nilpotent only if at least one eigenvalue is 0, but if $k$ eigenvalues were 0 we could factor out $x^k$ from the characteristic polynomial but we can't get even one out.